# How to run a Stack Exchange Data Explorer query from R and return the results to the R session?

Tags: r

We can see the excellent [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) in the browser, and use it to run some TSQL. A random example could be: `SELECT * FROM Tags`

How can we run such a query from R, and return the results directly to the R session?

#### Note

I am aware we could use the Stack Exchange public data in Google BigQuery (e.g. using bigrquery, dbplyr etc), but I would like to avoid using this method

Comment: See David Robinson's stackr package

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper I will check it out now

Comment: I never used it tbh, so I m not sure if you can feed it sql, but the functionality should be there

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper I checked it out, it appears to offer some great features, but limited to the queries available through the SO API (not the nuanced and fairly large queries available if we write sql in the SEDE). AFAIK it can't process custom sql queries. Thanks a lot for the good suggestion.